# ¿por qué no puedo conectarme a mi cpanel?

Tags: php, cpanel

estoy usando la libreria phpseclib para conectarme via ssh a mi cpanel, el problema es que al momento de poner este código:

```
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
use phpseclib\Net\SSH2;
$ssh = new SSH2('www.domain.tld');
if (!$ssh->login('username', 'password')) {
exit('Login Failed');
}
echo $ssh->exec('pwd');
echo $ssh->exec('ls -la');
```

no se conecta a mi servidor, ya intenté mediante whm y cpanel y de ninguna de las formas funciona, solamente imprime "Login Failed".

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Supongo que en username y password estas mandando los datos que corresponde no?

Comment: Puede ser problema de firewall, dentro del Cpanel habilitaste la opción de acceso por ssh?